# preventing default actions when in canvas, but resume default actions when not using canvas?

Tags: events, canvas, keyboard

I have an `html5` game on my website and i have prevented the actions for the `AWSD keys` and `SPACEBAR`. The problem is the **comment section** under the game cannot be used (more specifically the `AWSD keys or SPACEBAR`);

Any ideas?

Here's my code, its pretty noob. Ignore the comments.

this is the function that references the key events:

```
function slide2() {
        drawSlide2();
        document.removeEventListener('click', mouseNext, false);
        document.addEventListener('click', mouseNext2, false);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', startCheckKeyDown2, false);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', startCheckKeyUp2, false);
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', startCheckKeyDown1, false);
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', startCheckKeyUp1, false);
}
```

event listeners for the awsd functions

```
function playGame() {
    drawBg(); 
    startLoop(); //we call this when the game loads
    updateHUD();
    document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp, false);
    notMoving = false;
}
```

and here are my keyCode functions

```
function checkKeyDown(e) { //e is a keyword or something we use to describe an event, whenever 
    var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which; //this is like an if statment except in one line // it gets the keyID from the differing ID's from different browsers. cross-browser 
    if (keyID === 38 || keyID === 87) {  //  **** Up arrow and W *****
        jet1.isUpKey = true;
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents default actions of the up and w key funcions, like scrolling up and down
    }
    if (keyID === 39 || keyID === 68) {  //  **** RIGHT & W *****
        jet1.isRightKey = true;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 40 || keyID === 83) {  //  **** DOWN or S *****
        jet1.isDownKey = true;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 37 || keyID === 65) {  //  **** LEFT or A *****
        jet1.isLeftKey = true;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 32) {  //  **** SPACEBAR *****
        jet1.isSpacebar = true;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
} 

function checkKeyUp(e) { 
    var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (keyID === 38 || keyID === 87) {  //  **** Up arrow and W *****
        jet1.isUpKey = false;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 39 || keyID === 68) {  //  **** RIGHT & W *****
        jet1.isRightKey = false;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 40 || keyID === 83) {  //  **** DOWN or S *****
        jet1.isDownKey = false;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 37 || keyID === 65) {  //  **** LEFT or A *****
        jet1.isLeftKey = false;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    if (keyID === 32) {  //  **** SPACEBAR *****
        jet1.isSpacebar = false;
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, show us some code.

Comment: Here you go, it is quite noob, and may confuse you. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick answer is to let canvas handle it's own key events:**

1. Enable canvas to get keydown events: yourCanvas.setAttribute("tabindex",0);
2. Listen for keydown events: yourCanvas.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeydown,true);
3. In handleKeydown, prevent event bubbling: event.preventDefault();